# Numbered lists display fine after newline only if the first item starts with 1; otherwise, they need an extra newline in between

Tags: support, markdown, list, commonmark

See this markdown:

```
hello
1. Point 1
2. Point 2

bye
2. Point 2
3. Point 3
```

Now see how it renders:

hello

1. Point 1
2. Point 2

bye
2. Point 2
3. Point 3

As you see, the numbered list items just display properly if the first item has the `1` before it. The block starting with "bye" doesn't show the numbered list properly.

To have the second code block work, you need to add an extra line in between:

```
bye

2. Point 2
3. Point 3
```

Which renders well:

bye

2. Point 2
3. Point 3

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a CommonMark rule exception for ordered list markers.

> **[5.2 List items](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#ordered-list-marker)**
>
> The following rules define list items:
>
> Exceptions:
>
> 1. When the first list item in a list interrupts a paragraph—that is, when it starts on a line that would otherwise count as paragraph continuation text—then (a) the lines Ls must not begin with a blank line, and **(b) if the list item is ordered, the start number must be 1.**

Both `hello` and `bye`, as used in the example, are considered paragraphs by CommonMark.

> **[4.8 Paragraphs](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#paragraphs)**
>
> A sequence of non-blank lines that cannot be interpreted as other kinds of blocks forms a paragraph.

Each paragraph is interrupted by a list, which does not need an empty line to separate the paragraph from the list

> **[5.3 Lists](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#lists)**
>
> In CommonMark, a list can interrupt a paragraph. That is, no blank line is needed to separate a paragraph from a following list:
>
> Example 273. (...)

In conclusion, the first rule mentioned is applied to the `list items` in paragraph `bye` because they interrupt the paragraph without a blank line in between, and in that case the exception is that: *"if the list item is ordered, the start number must be 1"*.

The solution would be to use a blank line between the paragraph and the first list item to avoid the mentioned exception that will otherwise force the numbering to start at 1.

Comment: Thanks! What is weird is that both blocks themselves look exactly the same, so there is no _external_ indicator that one is a numbered list, while the other is not considered as such. For this, the behaviour looks buggy.