# Parenthesis's for numbered lists in posts with indented code not working in the live Post

Tags: bug, edits, markdown-preview, commonmark

When [CommonMark was adopted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark), it added support for [numbered list that use `1)`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348753/342074) as the markdown.

I was looking at [this answer from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1478915/6530134) on Stackoverflow and saw that it contained "1)".  Before a few minutes ago, I actually didn't know CommonMark added this functionality.  So I went to edit this post to make it `1.`, but before making any changes, the edit preview looks like so:

[image: edit preview]

The preview renders the markdown for the numbered list correctly, however the post itself still shows as "1)" and "2)".  Additionally, the code highlighting is not working in the preview, but in the post it is. I suspect it is something to do with the indentation of the code and the `1)` markdown.  I haven't made an edit yet to address it since I'm unsure if this is a bug?

I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355867/numbered-lists-display-fine-after-newline-only-if-the-first-item-starts-with-1) and I don't *think* its the same, but I am not sure.  Either way it seems off somehow.

Comment: This is essentially a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280149/323179), though the formatting is slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Laurel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/323179/laurel) was right with her [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380424/parenthesiss-for-numbered-lists-in-posts-with-indented-code-not-working-in-the/380425#comment1269113_380424), pointing out as to why this happens. Which is answered perfectly clear [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280148/why-does-this-markdown-preview-differently/280149#280149) by staff member [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson). TLDR: The post hasn't been re-rendered since the change of the markdown parser, and is thus still cached in its old state.

There is something else going on however, as to why the code isn't properly formatted.

The official Markdown [documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list) states:

> List items may consist of multiple paragraphs. Each subsequent paragraph in a list item must be indented by either 4 spaces or one tab:

Effectively by switching this into a propperly formatted list, the code has become a paragraph that is linked to the list item above. To have it be formatted as code there are two options:

1. format using a code fence like so:

   ```
   test code here
   ```
2. Indent with an extra set of spaces:

   ```
   test code here
   ```

You can click the edit button and see the difference.

Comment: So basically, the solution is to edit that post to re‐render a new cached copy.

Comment: Yes @TimothyG. Doing so wil cache a new HTML version of the post.